# Composer could not find the config file: C:\composer To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file

Tags: json, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install Laravel on my Windows 10, I have set composer in PATH.

The steps that I have executed were:
create a folder called `laravel` in htdocs folder of xampp `C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel`, then I used

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel
```

to access this folder then I ran the command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel
```

While installing, I got this error

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Composer could not find the config
>   file: C:\composer
>   To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: do you ensure that composer installed on C:\Composer directory  before to create environment variable?

Comment: yes i m sure , i already copy the path and paste it

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the environment variable. Try Control Panel-->System-->Edit the system environment variables-->Environment variables-->composer-->delete

Then try to create the laravel project normally.